# SharedPreferences being saved/loaded in onPause() and onCreate()

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I noticed sometimes that when using SharedPreferences, you can save arbitrary values in the onPause() method.

However, I also see that the contents from the SharedPreferences can be reloaded in the onCreate() method. And it seems to work, and I don't know why.

Why wouldn't these preferences (for example) get loaded in onResume() instead? As far as I know, clicking the back button and leaving the app doesn't destroy the activity, it just pauses it.

See this diagram for the Android lifecycle: http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png

I don't understand why it is essentially calling onCreate() again.

Comment: You're question isn't making a lot of sense-  SHaredPreferences aren't bound to the Activity lifecycle.  You can load and write them whenever.

Comment: Also clicking the back button does finish the Activity.

Comment: WHy wouldn't they?  THey have nothing to do with the Activity lifecycle.  You can write them whenever.  One of their purposes is to communicate between different Activities/Services.

Comment: No it doesn't.  That's not what SHaredPreferences do.  You're totally confused

Comment: WHat you're talking about is the saved instance state.  Which is cleared when you hit the back button, because hitting the back button finishes the Activity.

Comment: No you aren't.  What you are talking about is NOT SharedPreferences.  SharedPreferences is an API to write a settings file and have NOTHING to do with Activites or its lifecycle.  You are talking about somethign totally different.

Comment: I have no idea what tutorial you're looking at.  But shared preferences can be written and read anytime you want.  They have nothing to do with the activity lifecycle.

Comment: By the way-  you're working on tutorials.  I have 2 apps with over 100M downloads.  I suggest you listen rather than insist you know what you're talking about.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just voting to close an putting you on my never help list.

Comment: You'd think the fact that multiple people are giving you the same answer would be enough to prove you're being a moron.

Comment: Because why wouldn't it?  There's nothing special about onPause or onCreate that would stop it..

Comment: No.  Well, somewhat.  Rotating destroys then creates a new one passing in the Bundle created in saveInstanceState.  Back button does not call saveInstanceState.  But neither does anything with SharedPreferences.

Comment: Anyways I think I found my own answer, as onCreate() is called each time we press back/re-enter the app.

Answer (score 2):

**First thing first:**

### Shared Preferences are controlled by **YOU**, not the activity life cycle.

So, I believe your question is "When do the shared preferences get saved"?

AND the answer is, when you call the `commit` or `apply` method on the Shared Preference object, after editing it with the shared preferences. Here is how:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(NameAndId, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Ruchir");
 editor.putInt("personId", 21);
 editor.commit();
```

Now, If I want to get the name of the person, Ruchir, and the Id of the person, 21, I do this:

```
pref.getString("name", null); // getting Ruchir

pref.getInt("personId", null); // getting 21
```

In **NO WAY** is the activity life cycle controlling what gets saved. It is **YOU** calling the `apply()` or `commit()` method.

[image] (mrbool.com)

Comment: Because you're using the wrong terms.  SharedPreferences are a thing, and what you're talking about is a thing.  But they are totally different concepts.